# How to create custom cards (like adaptive cards) in botframework webchat using React.js?

Tags: reactjs, botframework, adaptive-cards, web-chat

I would like to create custom cards (like adaptive cards,hero card carousel model) in Botframework Webchat using Reactjs. Is it possible to create custom cards in webchat. If yes how can i achieve that. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Hey, not sure if i get you here. You want to create your own "cards" solution from scratch? or you want to build your own cards and use them?

Comment: Hi Tim, yes i want to create new cards to my existing bot application which is built using webchat and react js. I'm looking for something like this https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/05.custom-components/e.card-components

Comment: Well, to build your own cards and use them its best to start with the designer as such. go to www.adaptivecards.io/designer and play with it, you can always see the generated JSON to see which of the controls actually create which JSON. Once you are familar with how to create the cards ( i just admitted you are not, sorry! skip if you are) You can start thinking about how to build your own properly. I made tons of examples on how to use AdaptiveCards outside of like Teams. You can definitely just use adaptive cards technology (the js scripts etc) for your own bot.

Comment: AdaptiveCards as such is an open source tech you can freely use, its not a "Microsoft" tech as such. I sadly don't have any examples for react but this is one thing i made for Vue.JS https://github.com/deejaytc/adaptivecards-vue , should be similar

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but Its not like that Tim. My existing cards were already built using json. Actually i want to know is there any way i can create and customize using react. like there is an npm package for adpative cards right. Is that possible?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215640/discussion-between-thomas-martin-and-tim-cadenbach).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use AdaptiveCards inside your own application, using any JS framework, the team behind cards made 3 packages available:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/adaptivecards-templating
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/adaptivecards
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/adaptivecards-designer

You can fully implement Adaptive Cards functionality in your own apps outside of any Microsoft environment.

The official guide around that can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/rendering-cards/getting-started

Some further guides and examples can be found here:

- https://www.madewithcards.io which shows a lot of sample cards
- https://www.github.com/teamwork/vscode-projects a vscode extension
  made with cards
- https://medium.com/@tim.cadenbach/adaptive-cards-what-else-can-you-use-them-for-1cf6f9819c1a

There also are quite a few tools for various JS Frameworks like Vue.JS or React or Flutter. Also Webcomponents. You can find most of the tools here: https://www.madewithcards.io/tools/

Comment: Using the NPM packages also allows you to customize available card elements and controls to your own needs, add custom styling and events. However, cards made for your own host won't support the custom elements anywhere else.

Comment: hi tim do you have any idea on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62716870/how-can-i-clear-the-chat-input-box-after-sending-the-messagefrom-suggestion-in