# How can i clear the chat input-box after sending the message(from suggestion) in botframework webchat?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, botframework, direct-line-botframework, web-chat

i'm working on a bot application using react js and botframework webchat. The thing is that i want to clear the text input box (from where msgs are sent) after sending the message - which is selected from the suggestion. The Suggestion list(or autocomplete component) is a custom coded one. And What i mean is that if i type "hr" the suggestion list popup will come and if i click on one option from the suggestion, say 'hr portal', it will be sent, but what i wrote ie "hr" remains there in the input field and i want to clear that. And please note that If i type something and send its working fine. The problem is only when i type something and select something from the suggestion. Everything else is fine. How can i clear that. Any help would be really appreciated.

please find the below image for more understanding.

[image]

here's my code;

```js
import React from 'react';
import { DirectLine, ConnectionStatus } from 'botframework-directlinejs';
import ReactWebChat from 'botframework-webchat';
import './ChatComponent.css';
var val;
var apiParameters = [];
var currentFocus = -1;
export default class extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            token: '',
            conversationId: '',
            directLine: {},
            view: false,
            feedBack: null,
            value: '',
            popupContent: '',
            storeValue: '',
            suggestions: [],
            suggestionCallback: '',
            suggestionTypedText: "",
            typingChecking: "false",
        };
        this.handleTokenGeneration = this.handleTokenGeneration.bind(this);
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSaveFeedback = this.handleSaveFeedback.bind(this);
        this.handleSuggestion = this.handleSuggestion.bind(this);
        this.handleClose = this.handleClose.bind(this);
        this.handleSuggestionClick = this.handleSuggestionClick.bind(this);
        this.handleKeyDown = this.handleKeyDown.bind(this);
        this.moveHighlight = this.moveHighlight.bind(this);
        this.getSuggestionHtml = this.getSuggestionHtml.bind(this);
    }
    getSuggestionHtml(suggestion) {
        const lowerCaseSuggestion = suggestion.toLowerCase();
        return {
            __html: lowerCaseSuggestion.includes(this.state.suggestionTypedText) ? lowerCaseSuggestion
                .replace(this.state.suggestionTypedText, `<b>${this.state.suggestionTypedText}</b>`) : lowerCaseSuggestion
        };
    }
    handleTokenGeneration = async () => {
        console.log("11111");
        const response = await fetch(`api/TokenGenerationService/GetToken`);
        const data = await response.json();
        this.setState({
            token: data.categoryObject.token, conversationId:
                data.categoryObject.conversationId
        });
        this.state.directLine = new DirectLine({ token: this.state.token });
        this.setState({ view: true });
        this.setState({ typingChecking: "true" });
        console.log("conversationId");
    };
    async handleSuggestion(val, store) {
        if (val === "") {
            this.setState({
                suggestions: []
            });
        }
        else {
            apiParameters = [];
            var valuess = null;
            const response = await fetch(`api/TokenGenerationService/GetAzureSearch?myparam1=${val}`);
            const data = await response.json();
            var values = ["Hello", "yes", "no", "exit", "Welcome", "Thank You", "Approve", "Apply leave", "Reject", "Absence Balance", "Leave Balance", "Upcoming Holidays", "Apply Comp-Off", "Approve Leave", "Raise Incident Tickets", "Project Allocation Info", "Reporting Manager Change", "Reporting Manager Approval", "Approve Isolve Tickets", "My Manager", "My Account Manager", "Generate Salary Certificate", "Isolve Ticket Status", "Internal Job Posting", "My Designation", "My Joining Date", "RM Approval", "RM Change", "Resource Allocation", "ESettlement Approval", "SO Approval", "Cash advance Approval", "Purchase Request Approval", "Referral status", "HR Ticket", "Platinum Support"];
            valuess = values.filter(s =>
                s.toLocaleLowerCase().startsWith(val.toLowerCase())
            );
            valuess = valuess.concat(data.az_search);
            this.setState({
                suggestions: valuess,
                suggestionCallback: store,
                suggestionTypedText: val.toLowerCase()
            });
            // alert(data.az_search);
            var totCount = data.az_search;
            console.log("kkkkkk" + totCount);
        }
    }
    moveHighlight(event, direction) {
        event.preventDefault();
        const { highlightedIndex, suggestions } = this.state;
        if (!suggestions.length) return;
        let newIndex = (highlightedIndex + direction + suggestions.length) % suggestions.length;
        if (newIndex !== highlightedIndex) {
            this.setState({
                highlightedIndex: newIndex,
            });
        }
    }
    keyDownHandlers = {
        ArrowDown(event) {
            this.moveHighlight(event, 1);
        },
        ArrowUp(event) {
            this.moveHighlight(event, -1);
        },
        Enter(event) {
            const { suggestions } = this.state;
            if (!suggestions.length) {
                // menu is closed so there is no selection to accept -> do nothing
                return
            }
            event.preventDefault()
            this.applySuggestion(suggestions[this.state.highlightedIndex]);
        },
    }
    handleKeyDown(event) {
        // console.log("lokkkkkkkkkkkk")
        if (this.keyDownHandlers[event.key])
            this.keyDownHandlers[event.key].call(this, event)
    }
    async handleSuggestionClick(event) {
        await this.applySuggestion(event.currentTarget.textContent);
    }
    async applySuggestion(newValue) {
        //newValue = null;
        await this.setState({ typingChecking: "false", suggestions: [], highlightedIndex: 0 });
        this.state.suggestionCallback.dispatch({
            type: 'WEB_CHAT/SEND_MESSAGE',
            payload: {
                text: newValue
            }
        });
        await this.setState({ typingChecking: "true" });
    }
    getSuggestionCss(index) {
        var HIGHLIGHTED_CSS = "HIGHLIGHTED_CSS";
        var SUGGESTION_CSS = "SUGGESTION_CSS";
        return index === this.state.highlightedIndex ? HIGHLIGHTED_CSS : SUGGESTION_CSS;
    }
    handleClose(elmnt) {
        var x = document.getElementsByClassName("autocomplete-items");
        for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            if (elmnt !== x[i]) {
                x[i].parentNode.removeChild(x[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    async componentDidMount() {
        try {
            await this.handleTokenGeneration();
            const store =
                window.WebChat.createStore(
                    {},
                    ({ getState }) => next => action => {
                        this.state.directLine.connectionStatus$
                            .subscribe(connectionStatus => {
                                if (connectionStatus === ConnectionStatus.ExpiredToken) {
                                    console.log("expired");
                                }
                                if (action.type === 'WEB_CHAT/SET_SEND_BOX') {
                                    const val = action.payload.text;
                                    if (this.state.typingChecking === "true") {
                                        this.setState({
                                            highlightedIndex: -1,
                                        });
                                        console.log(this.state.typingChecking);
                                        this.handleSuggestion(val, store);
                                    }
                                }
                                if (action.type === 'DIRECT_LINE/DISCONNECT_FULFILLED') {
                                    console.log("final" + connectionStatus);
                                    console.log("finalexpired" + ConnectionStatus.ExpiredToken);
                                    console.log("final");
                                    this.handleTokenGeneration();
                                }
                            });
                        return next(action)
                    }
                );
            this.setState({ storeValue: store });
        } catch (error) {
            console.log("error in fetching token");
            console.log(error);
        }
        this.state.directLine.activity$
            .filter(activity => activity.type === 'message')
            .subscribe(function (activity) {
                //console.log("oooooooooooooooooooooo");
            }
                // message => console.log("received message ", message.text)
            );
    }
    handleSaveFeedback(ans) {
        // console.log(this.state.conversationId);
        //  console.log(this.state.feedBack);
        var userID = "C94570";
        var feedbackmsg = this.state.value;
        var feedbacktype = this.state.feedBack;
        var convId = this.state.conversationId;
        fetch('api/Feedback/SaveFeedback',
            {
                method: "POST",
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
                body: JSON.stringify({ Uid: userID, FeedbackMessage: feedbackmsg, Convid: convId, FeedbackType: feedbacktype })
            }).
            then(response => response.text())
            .then(data => {
                console.log(data.getResult);
            });
        this.setState({ value: '' });
    }
    feedback(ans) {
        this.setState({ feedBack: ans });
        if (ans === "Send") {
            this.handleSaveFeedback(ans);
        }
        else if (ans === "Yes") {
            this.setState({ popupContent: "How was your experience?" });
            // console.log(this.state.value)
        }
        else if (ans === "No") {
            this.setState({ popupContent: "What went wrong?" });
            // console.log(this.state.value)
        }
    }
    handleChange = (event) => {
        this.setState({ value: event.target.value });
    }
    styleOptions = {
        bubbleBackground: 'rgba(0, 0, 255, .1)',
        bubbleFromUserBackground: 'rgba(0, 255, 0, .1)',
        botAvatarInitials: 'DIA',
        userAvatarInitials: 'ME'
    }
    render() {
        if (!this.state.view) {
            return
            <div />
        } else {
            const filteredSuggestions = this.state.suggestions.filter(
                suggestion =>
                    suggestion.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.suggestionTypedText.toLowerCase())
                    > -1
            );
            //   console.log(this.state.view);
            return (
                <div className="react-container webchat" >
                    <div onKeyDown={this.handleKeyDown.bind(this)}>
                        <div >
                            <ReactWebChat styleOptions={this.styleOptions} directLine={this.state.directLine} webSocket={true} userID='C94570' username='Thomas' store={this.state.storeValue} sendTypingIndicator={true} />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="SuggestionParent" id="Suggestion1">
                        {this.state.suggestions.map((suggestion, index) => (
                            <div className={this.getSuggestionCss(index)} key={index} onClick={this.handleSuggestionClick} >
                                {suggestion
                                    .toLowerCase()
                                    .startsWith(this.state.suggestionTypedText) ? (
                                        <div>
                                            <b>{this.state.suggestionTypedText}</b>
                                            {suggestion
                                                .toLowerCase()
                                                .replace(this.state.suggestionTypedText, "")}
                                        </div>
                                    ) : (
                                        <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={this.getSuggestionHtml(suggestion)} />
                                    )}
                            </div>
                        ))}
                    </div>
                    <footer className="chat-footer" >
                        <div className="foot-footer">
                            Was I helpful ?
         <span className="feedback" onClick={() => this.feedback("Yes")} >Yes</span><span>|</span><span className="feedback" onClick={() => this.feedback("No")}>No</span>
                            {
                                this.state.feedBack === "Yes" || this.state.feedBack === "No" ?
                                    (
                                        <div className="dialog" id="myform">
                                            <div id="textfeedback">
                                                <span id="closeFeedback" onClick={() => this.feedback("Close")}>X</span>
                                                <p>{this.state.popupContent}</p>
                                                <input type="text" id="feedbacktxtbox" required name="textfeedback" placeholder="Pleasure to hear from u!"
                                                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                                                    value={this.state.value} />
                                                <button type="button" id="btnfeedback" onClick={() => this.feedback("Send")}>send</button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    ) : null
                            }
                        </div>
                    </footer>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Puhh sorry Thomas, don't think i can help here maybe try this: 
Chat.post($('input[name=\'content\']').val()); $('.input').val("")

Or else just clear with jquery?

Comment: @TimCadenbach thanks for the reply mate. Actually the problem is with the suggestion. I want to know if there is any way in react or bot action which can do that.

Comment: @ThomasMartin - Can you please fix your code? I pasted into Visual Studio and tried to format it and it became clear that there are missing braces, etc. Make sure the code runs and is nicely formatted (so don't have multiple blank lines in a row, etc.)

Comment: @KyleDelaney hi kyle thanks for the reply. ok i have formatted and updated the code. Please check

Comment: @ThomasMartin - Are you seeing what I'm seeing? Can you see that most of the code you posted has no indentation?

Comment: @KyleDelaney sorry for that but the code is working fine no problems at all. Please find the code from here https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/3288

Comment: I suspect you are trying to ask about the autocomplete component from your [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60524754/issues-with-suggestion-list-in-botframework-webchat-react). If that's the case, don't you think it would be a good idea to mention in your question somewhere that you've created your own autocomplete component so that the community has some context for your question? Please provide context because the community needs to understand your question in order to answer it.

Comment: @KyleDelaney what I'm expecting to achieve is explained in the question. I just need to clear the text after the suggestion is selected like shown in the image. How can I clear that if you know please help

Comment: @ThomasMartin - You need to understand that we don't know what you know. It may seem obvious to you what's going on in your project because you've been working on it, but the rest of us haven't been. There's nothing in your question that explains what "after the suggestion is selected" means because we don't know what you mean by suggestion. If you're talking about your own unique autocomplete component then that's a hugely important detail that needs to be in your question. You need to be willing to do the work of asking a question in a way that it can be answered.

Comment: @KyleDelaney I'm sorry for that. You helped me with building the autocomple component so I thought you'd be familiar with the code and you could possibly know the problem that's why I said that. Can you be more specific what more you need to understand from my question?

Comment: @KyleDelaney The question is updated.

Comment: Questions you ask on Stack Overflow should not be directed at one specific person.

Answer (score 1):

The chat input box is called the send box in Web Chat. Clearing the send box is just setting the send box with an empty string. This is done automatically when you click on the send button normally. You can see in the [submit send box saga](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/master/packages/core/src/sagas/submitSendBoxSaga.js) that submitting the send box means performing two actions: sending the message and setting the send box.

> ```
> if (sendBoxValue) {
>   yield put(sendMessage(sendBoxValue.trim(), method, { channelData }));
>   yield put(setSendBox(''));
> }
> ```

This means that if you use the `SUBMIT_SEND_BOX` action then the send box will be cleared automatically. Of course, if you want that to work with your autocomplete component then you'll need to set the send box with the autocompleted text before you submit it. Your other option is to just use the `SET_SEND_BOX` action with an empty string after you send the message.

Comment: so can i use `SUBMIT_SEND_BOX` INSTEAD OF `SEND_MESSAGE` ? And what do you mean by "you need to set the sendbox with the autocompleted text before you submit it". And please note that I changed from `SET_SEND_BOX`  to `SEND_MESSAGE` action because i was not able to send the message from suggestion pop-up when an opton is selected by enter or mouse click. Using `SEND_MESSAGE` its working fine.

Comment: There's no way you can do what you want to do with just one action. You can use SET_SEND_BOX + SUBMIT_SEND_BOX or you can use SEND_MESSAGE + SET_SEND_BOX.

Comment: hey kyle i just cleared it by making the following change, PFA, https://github.com/thomas023/Webchat/blob/master/ClearSendBox.txt now there is a problem that, the suggestion pop up is not closing when if i type something and try to remove that by pressing backspace. For instance if i type hr and hit backspace the suggestion pop up for h will stay there. How can i fix that?

Comment: Are you saying this is behavior that you hadn't observed before and has only been introduced by your new code that clears the send box? In any case, I don't think I can possibly know how to help you based on the information you've given me. I get the impression you're still a beginner so my advice is to take some courses on React, JavaScript, UI, and programming fundamentals. If you don't do that then you're going to keep getting in over your head and running into problems that you can't solve on your own. Once you've given it a good try then you should ask a new question with all the details.

Comment: actually the problem is with the suggestion popup (autocomplete component) that it is not closing even when the typed text is cleared using backspace. The suggestion list with the last removed word is not closing. That's the issue.

Comment: Is that new behavior or preexisting behavior?

Comment: it was pre-existing one which i only found it now.

Comment: Then you should ask a new question like I said. Follow the Stack Overflow guidelines by making an effort to solve the problem on your own first. Explain what solutions you've attempted already, and provide relevant sample code. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask